# Can't access app with curl when using Flask-Kerberos

Tags: python, curl, flask, kerberos

I am unable to access a Kerberos enabled Flask app when the app is run Flask-Kerberos instead of Apache with Kerberos.

When the script is run under Apache (where Apache is Kerberos enabled), I can access the url with curl (using the `--negotiate` option) as well as from a browser.

When the script is run as standalone using Kerberos-Flask, I can access the url from a browser, but not from curl.  I get the following error with curl.

```
@krbapp.route('/')
@requires_authentication
def index(user):
    return "Hello, World!"
```

```
curl  --negotiate -u foo http://server:5113
Enter host password for user 'foo':
```

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1->py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1->py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1->py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1->py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1->py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1->py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1->py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1->py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask_Kerberos-1.0.3->py2.7.egg/flask_kerberos.py", line 112, in decorated
    ctx.kerberos_token]) 
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string, NoneType found
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround. This seems to be bug in Kerberos flask library but will need to dig more. Commented out below two lines in Flask_Kerberos-1.0.3 library and now it works.

#    response.headers['WWW-Authenticate'] = ' '.join(['negotiate',

#                                                     ctx.kerberos_token])

curl curl  --negotiate -u: http://server:5005/

Hello, World!

and yes, it still performs Kerberos authentication after we comment out above two lines.

curl  http://server:5005/

Unauthorized

I hope this will be useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried curl with options`--user username:password`. For now as I see you pass the username without password.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. much appreciated. Tried your suggestion, same error. I think the issue is with curl not being able to pass authentication info to flask or flask not being able to understand auth info received from curl.

Comment: ha.. Found a work around. This seems to be bug in Kerberos flask library but will need to dig more.             #    response.headers['WWW-Authenticate'] = ' '.join(['negotiate',
            #                                                     ctx.kerberos_token])